# doesn't load assembly after The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I am seeing an odd issue where once an assembly fail to load, it does not load from a different process that had the same parent process.
Say there is Parent.exe that first create Child1.exe and it tries to load an assembly using

```
Type.GetType("TypeName, AssemblyName1")
```

and it fails because the assembly was not in probe path. I get expected warning:

> WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly

But when Parent.exe creates Child2.exe and AssemblyName1 is in its probe path, it still can't load AssemblyName1. Fusion log shows that it didn't even try to probe and gives error message

> LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr =
>   0x80070002

Am i seeing this because both Child1.exe and Child2.exe were created from Parent.exe?

I am confused. I understand load context is shared in app domain but i've never seen the load failure cache being shared across processes. Maybe i am misdiagnosing this?